# unable to write to file with PHP cURL with curlopt_stderr and curlopt_file

Tags: php, logging, curl

I'm trying to log the information from a cURL hit into a log file but am unable to do so,
I run windows with wamp and have given full control to all users in the machine and the log and php file that invokes cURL are in same directory for this test. I've used the below code:

```
$session = curl_init();
$logfh = fopen("my_log.log", 'a+');
if ($logfh) {
  print "Opened the log file without errors";
}
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Optional settings for debugging
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FILE, $logfh); // logs curl messages
// curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_STDERR, $logfh); // logs curl messages
curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
```

The log file opens without error and my cURL returns success but nothing is logged into the file.I've used `CURLOPT_FILE` and `CURLOPT_STDERR` alternatively but neither help the cause and not sure if i got something wrong here. Any suggestions on debugging this would be appreciated.

Comment: I do not see your call to [`curl_exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php).  Is something missing from your example?

Comment: you forgot `$session = curl_init();`

Comment: @Lee felt those were obvious because i specified curl returned success(200) but edited the question

Comment: Check the return value from `curl_exec()`, e.g. `$status = curl_exec($session); if (!$session) die(curl_error($session));`

Comment: If you are using the file in the same script, please make sure you close the file with fclose and then access it, otherwise it will be an incomplete file

Comment: [`fopen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) returns `FALSE` on *failure*.  So if your code (as shown above) is printing `"Opened the log file without errors"`, then your `fopen()` is actually failing, and your file isn't open.  (Also - that's not how you call `curl_init()`.  It should be `$session = curl_init($url)`; but I'm going to assume that you consider this "obvious" as well)

Comment: @Lee made some obvious mistakes :) corrected my question again... thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: If the URL you are trying to curl redirects to another URL, then writing output to a file WILL fail.

Please make sure you add the following line also-

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
```

Also as a side note, make sure you close the file with `fclose()` to make sure the file is complete.

Comment: thanks for the response, i've set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` and `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS`, however haven't done `fclose()`... will give it a try

Answer (score 4):

If you've added `fclose()`, and made the various "little fixes" listed in the comments above, but it's still not working... then I suspect that you're seeing conflicting options:

- `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` tells curl to return the response as the *return value* of the `curl_exec()` call.
- `CURLOPT_FILE` and `CURLOPT_STDERR` tell curl to write the response (or error output) to a specified file handle.

Seems like these may be mutually exclusive.  I would suggest that you use one or the other, but not both:

Either use `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, like this:

```
$session = curl_init();
$logfh = fopen("my_log.log", 'a+');
if ($logfh !== false) {
  print "Opened the log file without errors";
}
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$result = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
fwrite($logfh, $result);
fclose($logfh);
```

*or* use `CURLOPT_FILE`, like this:

```
$session = curl_init();
$logfh = fopen("my_log.log", 'a+');
if ($logfh !== false) {
  print "Opened the log file without errors";
}
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FILE, $logfh);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
fclose($logfh);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was the `fclose()` :)

Answer (score 0):

There could be also issue while using `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT` = true. I guess there is something in `CURLINFO_VERBOSE` that uses this option and just supress VERBOSE information...

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('log.log', 'a+'));
```

Just to mention, you can use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('log.log', 'a+'));
```

If you want to log output to file and still be able to return `curl_exec`.